# Mockito Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, firebase, mocking, mockito, instrumentation

I am trying to use `Mockito` to perform Instrumentation Testing in Android.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Mock
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    @Mock
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Mock
    private LoginView view;

    @InjectMocks
    private LoginActivityPresenter presenter;

    @Test
    public void validateInput() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2 + 2, 4);
    }
}
```

After running the `validateInput` test, I am seeing "No tests were found" and "Empty test suite." Would you be able to tell me what I am doing wrong? It works perfectly if I write the same code for a typical unit test class.

**Note:** I am just experimenting with Mockito and UI testing. I acknowledge that I could test the presenter only.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply run Mockito tests on Android, you need to activate an Android-compatible mock maker for this. This feature was added recently as the `mockito-android` artifact. It is documented in the `Mockito` class.

Comment: Could you summarize the answer here?